# Passing multiple variables in URL

Tags: ajax

If I do something like

```
var url = "dynamicprice.php";
httpObject.open("GET", url, true);
```

everything works, but if I try to pass variables

```
var url = "dynamicprice.php?package=" + document.getElementById('package').value + "&markup=" + document.getElementById('markup').checked;
httpObject.open("GET", url, true);
```

I get no answer from dynamicprice.

What do I have to change?

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to know exactly what the requests and responses are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the elements that you're referring to (`markup` and `package`) don't exist, then `url` is never created, and your request will never be sent. Try sticking `alert(url);` before `httpObject.open(...);` and make sure that you've got the right URL.

Answer (score 0):

Alert the values before constructing the url is your first best bet.Also alert the url after constructing it.

paste the url directly in the browser so that you can see any errors on server side